# How to add content to a modal dialog (kbModal.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found a modal dialog that i am using for my website but i don't know how to add content like buttons and styling it etc.

This is the link http://www.cssscript.com/creating-simple-modal-windows-with-kbmodal-js/

I have seen this but i dont know where to go from here:

```
 var modalOuterContainer = document.createElement('div');
            modalOuterContainer.className = 'dkKbModalOuterContainer';
            modalOuterContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="dkKbModalContainer dkKbModal dkKbFade">' +
                '<div class="dkKbModalDialog">' +
                    '<div class="dkKbModalDialogHeader">' +
                        '<button class="dkKbCloseButton">&times;</button>' +
                        '<h3 class="dkKbModalHeader"></h3>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="dkKbModalBody"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            var modalOverlay = document.createElement('div');
            modalOverlay.className = 'dkKbModalOverlay dkKbFade';
            document.body.appendChild(modalOuterContainer);
            document.body.appendChild(modalOverlay);
```

and this:

```
    addEvent(turnOnModal, 'click', function () {window.dkKbModal.show('Hello','Testing...');});
```

Please How do i use it to add content, Thanks alot !
Sorry for the nooby question

Answer (score 0):

You add them when you assign the event:

```
addEvent(turnOnModal, 'click', function () {window.dkKbModal.show('Check out my awesome button.','<input type="button" value=" Awesome " class="myawesomecssclass"/>');});
```